How would I load images for a custom local on iOS?
I want to add localization which can be controlled during runtime from within the app. I want to use Apple's localization solution for strings/colors/images. For strings, the issue is quite simple, I simply load the appropriate Bundle like so:
extension Bundle {
var bundleForLocalization: Bundle? {
    guard let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fr", ofType: "lproj") else { return nil }
    let url = URL(filePath: bundlePath)
    return Bundle(url: url)
}

And then load the strings themselves using the following method:
extension String {
    init(localized literal: String.LocalizationValue) {
        self.init(localized: literal, bundle: Bundle.bundleForLocalization)
    }
}

However for images/colors this does not work and the system cannot find the asset.
Is there anyway to load images/colors using the same manner?
Code tried
Please Note there is some experimentation like not using the Image initializer defined in the extension but I tried both ways.
Both color/images seem to be missing the actual error is as follow:
No image named 'LocalizedImage' found in asset catalog for <path to binary>/LocalizationTest.app/he.lproj

I checked out the actual folder structure in the final app and saw that indeed the lproj contains only a String file, and all localized assets seem to be just contained in an Assets.car file.
So this might be the reason as to why it doesn't work, although I definitely have seem people suggest something akin to this.
var bundleLocalizationKey: UInt8 = 0

extension Bundle {
    static var bundleForLocalization: Bundle? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &bundleLocalizationKey) as? Bundle
        }
        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &bundleLocalizationKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }
}

extension String {
    init(localized literal: String.LocalizationValue) {
        self.init(localized: literal, bundle: Bundle.bundleForLocalization)
    }
}

extension Image {
    init(name: String) {
        let image = UIImage(named: name, in: Bundle.bundleForLocalization, with: nil)
        self.init(uiImage: image!)
    }
}

extension Color {
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.init(name, bundle: Bundle.bundleForLocalization)
    }
}

final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        guard let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "he", ofType: "lproj") else { return }
        let url = URL(filePath: bundlePath)
        guard let bundle = Bundle(url: url) else { return}

        Bundle.bundleForLocalization = bundle
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var helloWorld = LocalizedStringKey("")

    @State var vm = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(helloWorld)
            Image("LocalizedImage", bundle: Bundle.bundleForLocalization)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            Color("LocalizedColor")
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear(perform: {
            helloWorld = LocalizedStringKey(String(localized: "Hello, world!"))
        })
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


Please post the code you tried, not just descriptions of it.

@ScottHunter I have added the code I tried :)

Also Apple recommends that per-app locales are selected via the settings app rather than in the app itself. This provides consistency for users and also means you will get automatic localisation.

Yeah I know that, but I have different requirements.
